# Web Scraping (Selenium)- only Spring 2019 shows up, and different results show up each time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, select, webdriver

Sometimes it prints out the outputs of the instructor if the input of the search engine is just the subject. Sometimes it just inputs the number. But my main problem is that it keeps printing out the instructors from the Spring 2019 term instead of Spring 2024. I've even tried using selects and ActionChains on it to make it select the dropdown menu, but it always seems to do 2 of the 3 correctly. Please help me out :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import time

instructor_seats = {}

#INPUTS
subject = input("What subject?")
number = input("What number?")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#URL
driver.get("https://catalog.apps.asu.edu/catalog/classes")

#SUBJECT AND COURSE NUM
search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "subject")
num = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "catalogNbr")

search.send_keys(subject)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
search.clear()

num.send_keys(number)
num.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
num.clear()




try:
    class_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "class-results"))
    )
    
    instructors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'class-results-cell instructor')]/a")
    open_seats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'class-results-cell seats')]")
    time_start = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'class-results-cell') and contains(@class, 'pull-left') and contains(@class, 'days')]/p")
    

    for instructor, seats, times in zip(instructors, open_seats, time_start):
        instructor_name = instructor.text
        seat = seats.text
        tim = times.text
        key = instructor_name + " " + tim
        instructor_seats[key] = seat[:2]

    for key, value in instructor_seats.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")

except:
    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```